# How can I get DataSet.WriteXml to include the scale/precision of a decimal field?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, xmlserializer

I have some code that uses a DataSet which is then serialized to XML. I am including the schema with it. Simplified, it's basically this:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    ds.WriteXml(ms, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
}
```

This almost works (well, it works without errors). Except the generated XML seems to be missing attributes like totalDigits/fractionDigits to constrain any decimal fields. Here's an example of what it returns for those:

```
<xs:element name="Price" msdata:ReadOnly="true" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
```

However, without it including the total # of digits / fractional digits the code that receives this info has no way of knowing what those should be (and unfortunately defaults to the max of both).

Is there a way to force the serializer to include this information? I'm kind of stuck here - this is really the ideal format as the client side (non .NET) can read this XML almost as-is and it's *almost* perfect. Except for this. If this was a one-off where I was only passing one type I'd just manually adjust or override it on the client side. But this effects a large number of things so that approach won't work.

**EDIT:** I haven't been able to find a way to do this automatically. I ended up writing code to pull the schema via .GetSchemaTable on a data reader, then using that info to adjust the schema generated by results from calling the DataSet's WriteXml method.

Comment: The attributes are probably in a different table.  The root tag is the name of the dataset.  The 2nd level tag are all your datatables.  The 3rd level tag is the column names and data.

Comment: Yes, the schema is included. The problem is that not ALL of the information about the field types is included.